# How to avoid for loop and use map or some other technique for below logic

Tags: apex, trigger, map, bestpractice, code

I have below code ,but not able to understand how i can avoid second for loop inside account
please suggest

```
    public static void getOpenCaseOnAccount() {
    Map<id,user> userIds = new map<id,user>([select id from user]);
    
    map<id,account> accountMap = new map<id,account>( [select id,createdbyid from account where createdbyid in :userIds.keyset()]);
    
    list<case> caseList =[select id,CaseNumber,accountid,Status from case where accountid in:accountMap.keyset()];
    
    map<id,case>caseMap = new map<id,case>();
    string caseNumbers='';
    for(account acc:accountMap.values()) {
        for(case c:caseList) {
            if(c.AccountId == acc.Id && c.status!='Closed' ){
                    caseNumbers += c.CaseNumber +'\n';
            }
        }
    }
    system.debug('caseNumber***'+caseNumbers);
}
```

Comment: See the `I need data from indirectly related records based on one or more input record fields` section in the above Q&A which demonstrates how to use maps for relating things together.

Comment: thanks phil W. in this example we can use nested query ,but in general as well if i wan to modify the above code to reduce the inside for loop..i just want to know how i can do that

Comment: like i tried Map<id,case>casemap= new map<id,case>()  for(case cs: caseList) {csmap.put(cs.accountid,cs)

Comment: Look at the detail of the sample code in that other Q&A - it demonstrates how to convert things to maps and then use those maps to do quick lookup. This will allow you to avoid nested loops like you have (which won't scale).

Comment: but in this ..only  one account and its one case is coming in map.. i am not sure how i can take list of cases and check in account for loop

Comment: Looking at your code, you don't actually need the outer account loop at all; just iterate over the caseList since you're guaranteed that the cases are only for the accounts in the accountMap anyway. You should also add the `Status != 'Closed'` to the query for cases so you can remove the if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do any maps here, at least with the sample code you have:

```
public static void getOpenCaseOnAccount() {
    Map<id,user> userIds = new map<id,user>([select id from user]);
    
    List<Account> accounts = [select id from account where createdbyid in :userIds.keyset()];
    
    List<Case> caseList =[select CaseNumber from case where accountid in :accounts AND Status != 'Closed'];

    string caseNumbers='';

    for(case c:caseList) {
        caseNumbers += c.CaseNumber +'\n';
    }

    system.debug('caseNumber***'+caseNumbers);
}
```

Note that I added the Status check to the Case query - why iterate cases that are not relevant? You don't need the Account map and can just use a list to directly get the Cases, then iterate those.

For other scenarios where you want to have a mapping, for example, from Account ID to all the Cases that match that Account ID, you could use maps like follows:

```
Map<Id, List<Case>> casesByAccountId = new Map<Id, List<Case>>();

// Iterate over the cases you have and put them into the map
for (Case case : cases) {
    List<Case> casesForAccount = casesByAccountId.get(case.AccountId);

    if (casesForAccount == null) {
        casesByAccountId.put(case.AccountId, new List<Case>{ case });
    } else {
        casesForAccount.add(case);
    }
}
```

This ensures you have all the cases matching a given Account ID, and you manage it in a very efficient manner. From that point on, when you have an Account ID you can simply get all the Cases for that Account ID from the map with `casesByAccountId.get(accountId)`.

Comment: thanks phil W. but still i want to see how I can generate the map and avoid for loop ..that can be helpful in somewhere else.

Comment: Look at the bulkifying query code in the Q&A I pointed you at. It clearly shows how to use maps instead of loops.

Comment: sure.thanks phil W. great help

Comment: Hi Phil W. the link u provided is using map ,where    // Note that in this contrived example we may have more than one case that matches
    // the Priority/ContactId combo. If so, this processing will keep the last Case matching
    // the given combination. It may be that you always have unique combinations for
    // your key values, you may want to use ORDER BY in the query to decide which to
    // keep or you may apply some other strategy for choosing which to keep,   ...................

Comment: ..So in my case i am getting only one case per account which is the problem..can u suggest or show me example where i can iterate map<id,list<cases>

Comment: I added an explanation for that, though it is really outside the scope of your original question (since you didn't actually need to use a map).